# Extract my contacts from hotmail/live

Tags: php, api, contacts, live, hotmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Export contact list from Gmail, Hotmail, Yahoo, LinkedIn, Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637560/export-contact-list-from-gmail-hotmail-yahoo-linkedin-facebook)

I wonder if there is a possibility to extract contacts from Hotmail/Live with the API (in PHP). and if it's possbile to have a real example.
Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

Try [Openinviter](http://openinviter.com/index.php). Its free for PHP.

Comment: I have already tried and it says "Unable to get contacts".